# Convert Uint8Array to string in javascript (with Chinese characters)

Tags: javascript

I am using the following code to convert a Uint8Array object to string:

```
var fileData = cc.FileUtils.getInstance().getByteArrayFromFile("file.txt");

// fileData is a Uint8Array object
var dataString = "";
for(i = 0; i < fileData.length; i++) {
    dataString += String.fromCharCode(fileData[i]);
}
alert(dataString);
```

and if the content of the "file.txt" is latin characters say

"this is a watch"

then the codes above works fine.

But, if there is non latin characters in the file say "thank you 谢谢"

then the convert result is not correct.

Hope someone can help me, thanks :)

Comment: How is the file encoded?  Are they standard unicode characters or do they use a special windows codepage?

Answer (score 0):

Not the solution, but to find the problem please verify the array by getting the character codes like this

```
var str= "thank you 谢谢";
for(i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    console.log(str.charCodeAt(i));
}
```

EDIT:

As it is giving `34` for `35874` it is clear that the character code is not coming in 16 bits. Because

**35874 = 10001100 00100010 => in 8 bits => 00100010 = 34**

Please check the encoding of the file. Also see whether you can specify the encoding in `getByteArrayFromFile` . Usually a charset is used to read multiple bytes as you can see in this as an example - [actionscript function](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html#readMultiByte%28%29)

Comment: I tried your code and the output is:
"
0: 116 
1: 104 
2: 97 
3: 110 
4: 107 
5: 32 
6: 121 
7: 111 
8: 117 
9: 32 
10: 35874 
11: 35874 
"

it seems everything is ok and then I tried:
var fileData = cc.FileUtils.getInstance().getByteArrayFromFile("file.txt");
//fileData = "thank you 谢谢";
for(i = 0; i < fileData.length; i++) {
    console.log(i + ": " + fileData[i]);
}

and the output is:
"
0: 116
1: 104
2: 97
3: 110
4: 107
5: 32
6: 121
7: 111
8: 117
9: 32
10: 34
11: 34 
"
the last two chinese characters is obvious wrong ~ but I don't know why (file.txt is UTF-8 formated)